# JStorage Max Allowed Size in browsers

Tags: javascript, jstorage

What is the max allowed size of [JStorgae](https://github.com/andris9/jStorage) in different browsers(including mobile browsers)? I want to know this since I want to calculate the minimum of all the max allowed sizes and based on that I want to store some number of objects so that it can be used without any issue across most(almost any) browser(be it desktop or laptop or tablet or mobile based).

Regards,
Sandip

Comment: Look here https://github.com/andris9/jStorage/issues and ask there too

Comment: @mplungian - Ok. Thanks. Asked it - https://github.com/andris9/jStorage/issues/105

Comment: As per the newly raised issue in Github, the answer seems to be 1MB and if more than that then it's advisable to use IndexedDB. Thanks once again @mplungjan for suggesting to raise a new issue with the JStorage Git Repo.